# What is the difference between vendor prefixes webkit and WebKit (diff case)?

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, vendor-prefix

I see that vendor prefix is used in smaller cases in some API (webkitURL, for example) and in camel cases in some API (WebKitBlobBuilder). What is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Reply from PhistucK on Chrome DevTools Google group:

Constructors have have their WebKit prefix capitalized. Members (properties, methods, events) have a lower cased prefix. URL is not a constructor, its naming is just a bit unconventional.
Blob is WebKitBlob
window.URL is window.webkitURL
navigator.getUserMedia is navigator.webkitGetUserMedia